# Does anyone know how i can get up movement on my sprite in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I know how to get left and right movement but does anyone know how to get up and down in pygame
i am using pygame locals, pygame, sys, glob. Any help would be greatly appreceated, most of the code is based of: https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/platform-game-in-detail-part-1/?doing_wp_cron=1603309265.4902870655059814453125

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import sys
import glob
map1 = """wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           
w                           d
w            p               
w                           
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"""
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/flappy-bird-assets-master/flappy-bird-assets-master/favicon.ico"))
pygame.display.set_caption("Knock Knight")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 250))
moving_right = False
moving_left = False
moving_up = False
moving_down = False
player_location = [50,50]#remember its a fucking list

#-----------------------------

door = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Door.png")
door_rect = door.get_rect(center=(100, 250))

tile = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Wall.png")
tile_rect = tile.get_rect(center=(100, 256))

player = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Player.png").convert()
player_rect = player.get_rect(center=(100, 256))



def init_display():
    global screen, tile, door, player


def tiles(map1):
    global tile, door, player
    for y, line in enumerate(map1):
        #counts lines
        for x, c in enumerate(line):
            #counts caracters
            if c == "w":
                #caracter is w
                screen.blit(tile, (x * 16.18, y * 15))
            if c == "d":
                screen.blit(door, (x * 16.2, y * 15))
            if c == "p":
                screen.blit(player, player_location)


map1 = map1.splitlines()
pygame.init()
init_display()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    tiles(map1)
    if moving_right == True:
        player_location[0] += 4
    if moving_left == True:
        player_location[0] -= 4
    if moving_up == True:
        player_location[0] +=8

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()



        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moving_up = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moving_up = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moving_down = False





    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: for the up and down movement you have to change the 2nd coordinate. e.g `player_location[1] += 4`

Answer (score 0):

The position of the player is defined by 2 coordinates (x, y). For the up and down movement you have to change the 2nd (y) coordinate (e.g. `player_location[1] -= 4`):

```py
while True:
    tiles(map1)

    if moving_right == True:
        player_location[0] += 4
    if moving_left == True:
        player_location[0] -= 4

    if moving_up == True:
        player_location[1] -= 4
    if moving_down == True:
        player_location[1] += 4
```